# Determine the range of $r$ in which $f $ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

If I choose $r=2$, I can find f is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$. But I can't find a range of $r$ in which question a. I am thinking about use Squeeze Theorem for limits.

[image]

Comment: In both parts, $x=0$ is the only problematic point. You should be able to write down a limit which is equal to 0 if and only if $f$ is continuous at 0. Can you do that? Similarly there is a limit which exists if and only if $f$ is (right-)differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Yes, I can but I am trying to find a range of r

Comment: It helps if you write down what you *are* able to do so that we can use it to express the steps that you aren't. Note that $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded, so $f(x) \to 0$ if and only if $x^r \to 0$. Does that tell you a range of $r$?

Comment: I think I got the point.  Limit which exists (Approaching zero from the right) have to be equal def. of derivative (at the appropriate points). This happens iff r>1 and derivative at 0 is 0.

Answer (score 1):

At $ (0,+\infty) $, $ f(x)=e^{r\ln(x)}\sin(\frac 1x) $ and

$$f'(x)=x^{r-2}(rx\sin(\frac 1x)-\cos(\frac 1x))$$

On the other hand
$$\forall x>0\; \; |f(x)|\le x^r$$
so if $ r>0 $, $ f $ is contiinuous at $ [0,+\infty) $
and
$$|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}|\le x^{r-1}$$
so, if $ r-1>0$, it will be differentiable.

If $ r\le 0$, we prove it is not continuous at $ 0$ by subsequences :
$$x_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}\;,\;y_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}$$

Comment: I think I made a mistake in option b. Because I have to find an interval r, but I tried to prove it by finding a point. I think I got it now, thank you.

Comment: How about if f′ exists and is differentiable on [0, ∞) ?

Comment: @RabiaK. $ f' $ is differentiable at $[0,+\infty( $ if $ r-3>0$.